# How do I store the content of a variable for later use in other function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, authentication, variables

I have been trying to make a simple Register/Login system in JS. I tried to get the username/password values through user inputs and turn them into variables using a register() function. After that, however, these variables no longer hold any value, and I need them to compare with the new login username/password to check if they match in order to login.

Here's what I tried.

The function below attributes the user's input to the respective variables successfully. The ID's are from a text input in a HTML file.

```
function register () {
    var user1 = window.document.getElementById('username')
    var pass1 = window.document.getElementById('password')
    alert('User registered, user your credentials to login')
}
```

When I click the 'register' button in the html page, the function is called (onclick="register()"), and I am redirected to the login page.

Here's the code for the login session:

```
function login () {
    let userL = window.document.getElementById('usernameL')
    let passL = window.document.getElementById('passwordL')

    if (userL === user1 && passL === pass1) {
        alert(`${userL} successfully logged`)
    }

    else {
        alert('Invalid credentials')
    }
```

It doesn't work because in the code above, user1 and pass1 are "not defined", according to the console. How do I keep the values of these variables stored after getting them in the first function(register) in order to use it when the second function(login) is used?

Comment: When you learn enough about variable scoping in JS, please note that you're comparing HTML elements themselves and not their text content.

Comment: To get the value of an input field use this: `ar user1 = window.document.getElementById('username').value;` (@PM77-1's condescending answer is not helpful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below code,

```
<script>
      const allUsers = [];

      function register() {
        // assuming user1 && pass1 are input elements with ids username, password
        var user1 = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var pass1 = document.getElementById("password").value;
        // TODO: always validate the data that is taken as input from the user

        // create an object containing user details
        const newUser = {
          username: user1,
          password: pass1,
        };

        // push the registered user in allUsers array
        allUsers.push(newUser);
        alert("User registered, user your credentials to login");
      }

      function login() {
        // assuming user1 && pass1 are input elements with ids usernameL, passwordL
        let userL = document.getElementById("usernameL").value;
        let passL = document.getElementById("passwordL").value;

        // TODO: always validate the data that is taken as input from the user

        // loop through allUsers array to check whether we already have a user registered with the details given in login form
        for(let user of allUsers) {
          if(user.username === userL && user.password === passL) {
            alert(`${userL} successfully logged`);
            return; // exit the function here
          }
        }

        // if user detail not found in allUsers array this alert will be executed
        alert("Invalid credentials");
      }
    </script>
```

- Store all users in array after successful registration
- While login, loop through the registered users array to check whether the user has already registered or not and decide how to handle the logic.
- As PM 77-1 mentioned in the comment, please be aware that getElementById(ID) returns us the element itself (the tag itself), if we want to access it text content we can use either `getElementById(ID).textContent` or `getElementById(ID).innerText`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Session storage** to store temporary data

```
sessionStorage.setItem('username',username);

sessionStorage.setItem('password',password);
```

To retreive the data in login page

```
var user1 = sessionStorage.getItem('username',username);

var pass1 = sessionStorage.getItem('password',password);
```

then clear

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```